# Is there any way to find out an argument passed to a jar was quoted?

Tags: java, shell, arguments

I'm trying to pass a number of arguments to my Java application, but I would like to parse them by myself using an intelligent parser that doesn't just rely on whitespace to separate the arguments. An example:

```
/update source=foo func=(bar, foo ,foo,bar)
```

This all works nicely by converting everything to tokens and then parse those. However, a problem occurs when I add:

```
path="./foo/bar/foo  bar.txt"
```

(note the double space between foo and bar).

When I use double quotes, the argument is passed as a single string, preserving the double space. The quotation marks are removed though like this:

```
path=./foo/bar/foo  bar.txt
```

which makes my parser fail. But when I try to use some other character to use as quotes, like ', the parser works fine but then the shell passes the string as two separate strings, separated at the double space, therefore I lose the information that there were two spaces there.

What can I do to pass an argument using double quotes to keep the literal string representation, but also keep the information that the string was quoted, without the user having to type weird constructions like "'string'"? I'm using Java, maybe there is a way to get the entire line of arguments unparsed by the shell? Or just without the quotes being removed?

Btw, I ran this from microsoft command line, haven't tried a unix shell yet, which might even fail on the single quotes from what I read on the interwebs

Comment: double space is a part of name?

Comment: yes, I know it's an odd name, but I was curious about it (in fact I'd rather just use double quotes than single quotes on the command line, but for now I've kept it single quote marks and hope no filenames will ever have double spaces in them...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help I got, but I already figured it out:

- I know the thing that could be quoted doesn't contain brackets, comma's or equals signs, the things that my parser recognizes.
- I know that IF something was quoted and it contained spaces, those spaces would still exist within the split argument.
- I know that the original string of arguments is split at every region of whitespace, so the final split arguments don't contain spaces, only those in the quoted parts.

Therefore I can assume that if I parse a split argument, that any space in there does not imply a new token has to be generated, therefore it is retained in the final string-token.

I just have to rewrite my tokenizer now to accept an array of arguments instead of the concatenated string I now create from the args array I get passed in my main() method. That way I can differentiate between skipping real whitespace (going into the next element of the array) and quoted whitespace (any other whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

On the Windows command line (using `cmd.exe`), you can escape double quotes with `\"`. For example,

```
java MyApp path=\"./foo/bar/foo bar.txt\"
```

will result in

```
args[0] = path="./foo/bar/foo
args[1] = bar.txt"
```

while

```
java MyApp path="\"./foo/bar/foo  bar.txt\""
```

will give you

```
args[0] = path="./foo/bar/foo  bar.txt"
```